# S7 Edge Messaging App Cannot Block a number that is not a contact

Tags: sms, call-screening, sms-blocking

I can block a number that is a contact such as my mum. But I cannot block numbers by companies such as my network proviser Three. By block I mean stop receiving annoying text messages,

[image]

It is not Three I am trying to block just using them as an example. I cannot add three to contact to perform block options that does not work. What is even more infuriating is that I cannot find a number to block its just "Three" with no phone number to be discovered anywhere.

How can I block these annoying text messages that are not even in my phones contacts.

I am using the default messaging app on the samsung galaxy s7 edge, fully updated, no modifications made.

Long pressing does not work either.

[image]

Comment: Try long pressing on the contact and select "block number"

Comment: That menu yields only "delete" and "pin" buttons, no block options. However with a number in my contacts the block option. Adding a picture to show this in my post. Thank you

Comment: I believe that it's the way that your carrier send you those texts, they make it impossible to block, as that don't send it using a number, your phone can't know when to block it. I'm also guessing that when you open the message, there is no place to write a text. Is that correct? Try an app called truecaller. It might be able to get past the issue, but you'll have to switch to their app for that

Comment: Thank you I will try the app. But this is not limited to my network provider three. I also cant block messages from Deliveroo a company I work for.

Comment: And yes that is correct there is no option to write a text